# Alter uploaded image before saving with Django admin models

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I have a Django model which saves an image. However before I save the model I want to check the width and height and create a md5 hash of the image to check for duplicate uploads.

I'm not using any custom forms I'm just trying to upload some images using the admin backend.

I'm using Django==3.0.5 and Python 3.8.2

This is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from hashlib import md5
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

class UploadedImage(models.Model):
    """An image upload

    Arguments:
        models {[type]} -- [description]
    """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    height = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    extension = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, default='')
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, unique=True, db_column='hash', default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @staticmethod
    def hash_exists(hash):
        return UploadedImage.objects.exists(hash=hash)

    def generate_name(self):
        img_id = UploadedImage.objects.values('id').order_by('-id').first()['id'] + 1
        self.name = "%s_%s" % (img_id, self.hash[-4:])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # get the actual image???????
        # img = self.request.FILES['image'] ????

        if img:
            self.hash = md5(img).hexdigest()
            try:
                if hash_exists(self.hash):
                    raise ValueError("image hash already exists, duplicate image!")
            except ValueError as err:
                print(err.args)
                return err
            img = Image.open(BytesIO(img))
            self.width, self.height = img.size
            self.extension = img.format.lower()
            self.generate_name()
        else:
            print("no image")
            return ""
        super(UploadedImage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However I cannot find anywhere how I can access the files which are send in the form.
How I can I access these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like this,

```
class UploadedImage(models.Model):
    # your code

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.image  # the image will be here
            # access any class variables using `self` member
        super(UploadedImage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

here the statement, **`if not self.pk`** is very important since it is used to identify whether the the `save` operation is handling a *new object* or not

Comment: Thanks this worked. Although one thing I don't understand. The file isn't stored in the upload_path yet. So how can Pillow open an image which isn't there yet?

Comment: I am not much sure about the Pillow thing, but [**`PIL.Image.open(fp, mode='r')`**](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) seems it accepts file pointer too